# Unity C# ArrayList of Objects Serialize into XML Utf8 - Primitive Error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, utf-8, unity-game-engine

I have a ArrayList with some user objects in. I am trying to serialize them into an XML format that I can send to a webserver. The format needs to be UTF 8.

I keep running into this error:

```
The type of the argument object 'User' is not primitive.
```

This is effectively two issues, however the main one being that this primitive error will not let me try and other web examples for utf8. I simply to not understand why it does this. I have tried using:

```
[Serializable]
```

Currently I have a function which will work but it will not do the xml to a utf8 format. And when I try any other examples on the web I then get this primitive error. Below is my current code:

My User Class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;


    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {
public int UserID { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public string Password { get; set; }

public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

public string DeviceMacAddr { get; set; }

public DateTime LastLoggedIn { get; set; }

public float LastLoggedLat { get; set; }

public float LastLoggedLong { get; set; }

public bool Active { get; set; }

public string SyncStatus { get; set; }

public DateTime LastSyncDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My XML writing Script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Collections.Generic;



    public class XmlWriting : MonoBehaviour {

        private string formatString = "'yyyy'##'MM'##'dd' 'HH'*'mm'*'ss'";
        [XmlAttribute("Users")]
        ArrayList Users = new ArrayList();


        //List<User> Users = new List<User>();

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {


            Users.Add(new User {    UserID = 1,
                                        Name = "Test Woman",
                                        Password = "aa",
                                        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                        DeviceMacAddr = "24:70:8c:83:86:BD",
                                        LastLoggedIn = DateTime.Now,
                                        LastLoggedLat = 36.083101f,
                                        LastLoggedLong = -11.263433f,
                                        Active = true,
                                        SyncStatus = "Awaiting Response",
                                        LastSyncDate = DateTime.Now,
                                    }
            );
            Users.Add(new User {    UserID = 2,
                                        Name = "Test Man",
                                        Password = "aa",
                                        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                        DeviceMacAddr = "74:21:0c:93:46:XD",
                                        LastLoggedIn = DateTime.Now,
                                        LastLoggedLat = 83.083101f,
                                        LastLoggedLong = -3.261823f,
                                        Active = true,
                                        SyncStatus = "Complete",
                                        LastSyncDate = DateTime.Now,
                                    }
            );

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, Users);

            byte[] utf8EncodedXml = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Debug.Log ("SerializeArrayList: " );//+ utf8EncodedXml);


        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

        }


        private string SerializeArrayList(ArrayList obj)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), new Type[]{typeof(User)});
            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    doc.Load(stream);
                    Debug.Log ("stream: " + doc.InnerXml);
                    return doc.InnerXml;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
        {
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
            }
        }


    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the [Serializable] attribute above the class definitions for User and every other class you intend to serialize. As for UTF-8, it shouldn't matter, at least not logically - C#'s deserializer on the other side should handle any encoding transparently for you.